# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" while loading "script.js"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress Theme and I Imported my `script.js` File in the `header.php` File with this Code:

```
wp_register_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js');
wp_enqueue_script('script');
```

and i get this Error while loading:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier script.js?ver=5.3.2:1

I can see whats in my `script.js` File via Browser, so it should be loaded, right?

**script.js**

```
function setID(int htmlID) {
    alert("DONE!"); 
    // var phpID = document.getElementById("phpID_" + htmlID).Value;
    // alert("htmlID -> " + htmlID);
    // alert("phpID -> " + phpID); 
}
function start() {
    alert("Yay, its Working!"); 
}
```

And if I click on a Button that calls a JS Function that is in my `script.js` File, i get this Error(the Funtion im calling named `start()`):

> VM36 :104 Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM36 :104)
>   It says, that it is not defined, so i think, that it has no access to the `script.js` File.

How can i fix it, that the script.js File is loading correctly AND that my `start()` function is called correctly, when pressing a button?

Comment: Share code wthin script.js

Comment: `function setID(int htmlID) {

    alert("DONE!");

    // var phpID = document.getElementById("phpID_" + htmlID).Value;

    // alert("htmlID -> " + htmlID);
    // alert("phpID -> " + phpID);
}
function start() {
    alert("Yay, its Working!");
}`

If i remove the first function, i can call `start()`, but with the first function its not working. My Buttons are calling the first function correctly, its calling `setID(2)`

Comment: UPDATE // I removed the parameters from setID, now everything is wokring fine, but the parameters are very important for me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay i got it.
Its because i used `int num`, but correct is to use just `num` in the parameter field of my `setID()` Function